# Outdated yarn lockfile error on deploying app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have successfully signed up on Heroku but when I `git push` and ran the [app](https://salty-reef-85130.herokuapp.com/), it says

`Application error. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command`

Then, I went to Heroku from the web browser and under "Manual deploy", I click "Deploy Branch" and get this list of errors:

```
    -----> Node.js app detected

    -----> Creating runtime environment

           NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
           NODE_ENV=production
           NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
           NODE_VERBOSE=false

    -----> Installing binaries
           engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
           engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
           engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)

           Resolving node version 10.x...
           Downloading and installing node 10.15.1...
           Using default npm version: 6.4.1
           Resolving yarn version 1.x...
           Downloading and installing yarn (1.14.0)...
           Installed yarn 1.14.0

    -----> Building dependencies
           Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
           yarn install v1.14.0
           [1/4] Resolving packages...
           error Your lockfile needs to be updated, but yarn was run with `--frozen-lockfile`.
           info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
    -----> Build failed
     !     Outdated Yarn lockfile
           Your application contains a Yarn lockfile (yarn.lock) which does not
           match the dependencies in package.json. This can happen if you use npm
           to install or update a dependency instead of Yarn.
           Please run the following command in your application directory and check
           in the new yarn.lock file:
           $ yarn install
           $ git add yarn.lock
           $ git commit -m "Updated Yarn lockfile"
           $ git push heroku master

           https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-outdated-yarn-lockfile
     !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
     !     Push failed
```

Can someone give me some pointers? I have no idea why it mentioned yarn. Here is my package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "tictacttoe",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": "v10.13.0",
        "npm": "6.4.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not ie <= 11",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.19.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's because of heroku or some faulty config at your end...but basically heroku is running `yarn` to install your dependencies, and since you dont have a `yarn.lock` (or have an outdated one), it is resulting in an error.

Try installing yarn globally on your system and running yarn on your project's root directory. After that if you commit the `yarn.lock` file it might work.

AFAIK, heroku detects your package manager from whether or not you have `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json` in it. So you should either delete `yarn.lock`, or update it by running `yarn` in your  project's root directory.

Comment: @hasany Basically the OPs error was that he had an outdated yarn lockfile. This can happen if you run something like `npm install --save package` while your package manager is supposed to be yarn. This will result in your `yarn.lock` being outdated (since the package.json changed while yarn.lock did not). The simplest way to fix this would be to run `yarn` on your project root to create the correct lockfile.

Comment: I understand it is credible but I have deleted the yarn.lock file and regenerated it by running yarn command, but still I'm getting same error. I have also tried pushing to heroku with missing yarn.lock file, but still same error message occurs, despite of that heroku generates yarn.lock file itself. I have read a post that mentions some packages may be missing in my package.json file.

Comment: can you post the exact error log? Maybe I can help debug what the cause of the error is.

Answer (score 1):

It is because Heroku is not able to find updated yarn lock file. Run the following commands and you should be good to go.

```
yarn install 
git add yarn.lock 
git commit -m "updating yarn" && git push
git push heroku master
```